# action for oncreateoptionsmenu

Tags: android

using the following i get the menu. but how to make any action when the menu is selected 
can anyone help me out. thanks in advance.

```
 public boolean OnCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    menu.add(1, 200, 0, "snapshot");
            menu.add("more");
            menu.add("exit");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

is it possible to make the action using the following. but the layout doesnt load while using the following

```
public boolean OnOptionsItemsSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case 200: setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Step #1: Rename `OnCreateOptionsMenu()` to `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, as Java is case-sensitive.

Step #2: Rename `OnOptionsItemsSelected()` to `onOptionsItemSelected()`, as Java is case-sensitive.

Comment: @radish: It works for tens of thousands of other developers. Here is one sample: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Menus/Menus

Comment: You missed removing a lower case `s` from `onOptionsItemSelected()` after `Item`, that is why he is still getting the error.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can! I believe you just mistyped to function-names.
This code works fine for me:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(1, 200, 0, "snapshot");
        menu.add("more");
        menu.add("exit");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 200:
                 setContentView(R.layout.main2);
                 return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: when i use @Override before the onOptionsItemSelected i get error in eclipse to remove the annotation

Comment: @radish: These methods need to be implemented on a subclass of `Activity`.

Comment: i get the following error when @override is used 

The method onOptionsItemsSelected(MenuItem) of type MjpegSample must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: Like CommonsWare just said, the class needs to extend Activity, I will edit my answer for full class code